# Cannot print on raw printer,

Tags: vb.net, printing

I'm trying to print raw data on a thermal-printer, but everytime I try to print I get an `PInvokeStackImbalance`.

I'm using [this](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;322090) example to print. And the exception always happens here:

```
    Public Shared Function SendBytesToPrinter(ByVal szPrinterName As String, ByVal pBytes As IntPtr, ByVal dwCount As Int32) As Boolean
    Dim hPrinter As IntPtr      ' The printer handle.
    Dim dwError As Int32        ' Last error - in case there was trouble.
    Dim di As DOCINFOW          ' Describes your document (name, port, data type).
    Dim dwWritten As Int32      ' The number of bytes written by WritePrinter().
    Dim bSuccess As Boolean     ' Your success code.

    ' Set up the DOCINFO structure.
    With di
        .pDocName = "My Visual Basic .NET RAW Document"
        .pDataType = "RAW"
    End With
    ' Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.
    bSuccess = False
    If OpenPrinter(szPrinterName, hPrinter, 0) Then
        If StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di) Then
            If StartPagePrinter(hPrinter) Then
                ' Write your printer-specific bytes to the printer.
                bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, dwWritten)
                EndPagePrinter(hPrinter)
            End If
            EndDocPrinter(hPrinter)
        End If
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter)
    End If
    ' If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
    ' about why not.
    If bSuccess = False Then
        dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
    End If
    Return bSuccess
End Function ' SendBytesToPrinter()
```

The exception is on this line `If OpenPrinter(szPrinterName, hPrinter, 0) Then`
I did some research but I don't know what is going on. Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

PInvokeStackImbalance errors are usually marshalling problems, caused by incorrect declarations. You don't say what you're running on, but if your DLLImport function looks like this:

```
Public Shared Function OpenPrinter(ByVal src As String, ByRef hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal pd As Long) As Boolean
```

Maybe try this instead (the last parameter is an Integer not a Long):

```
Public Shared Function OpenPrinter(ByVal src As String, ByRef hPrinter As IntPtr, ByVal pd As Integer) As Boolean
```

Hope this helps.